# Mesh/Model twists when moving root bone

Tags: bones

Root bone twists legs and arms at the connecting point of each bone, No clue why.

Here's what I mean

[image: enter code here]

And on default.

[image]

What I've tried so far is weight painting but it seems like it's not the cause of the problem nor does it effects it as far as I can tell. How ever when I'm moving the arms and legs only it worked completely fine. Just the root bone.

Comment: Hello, it's hard to understand what's happening, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Figured it out by adding limit rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding limit rotation seems to work for the most part.